# Bit in Jasperreport

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have saved in my DB an `Integer Field` and in my report (`JasperReport`) I need to divide the `Integer` to `Bit`.
How I can do this from the JasperReport Field Expression?

has some ready functions in jasperreport, but none of them solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go in JasperReport and pass as parameter of the class instead of using the database. In class fields they are already formatted for use Bit